# How to handle one express route different than all other

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm currently using the Express router within a NodeJS application. I have simply been using `app.use(app.router);` for routing and it works well.
However, I'm now testing out some new routes and want to handle them differently.

Ideally I would like to be able to say:

```
var vers2Router = require('./routes/version2');

app.use('/version2', vers2Router);
app.use(app.router);
```

Can I do this in order to handle all `/version2` routes with `vers2Router` and the rest simply using `app.router`?

Comment: This is right off the top of my head, so forgive me if I'm wrong - yes, this pattern would work (I used it somewhere) - but as far as I can remember, you want to overwrite specific routes (`/version2`) *after* defining global handler, not before (so `app.use(app.router)` would *precede* `app.use('/version2')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Express version 4.x, [`app.router`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#approuter) has been removed. Routes are now executed in the order they are added.

Now you may use the [express.Router](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x#router) because it will allow you to have isolated instances of routes and in your example you could create many routers with their own versioned routes.

Something like this:

```
// app.js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var userRouterV1 = require('./routes/v1/userRouter.js');
var userRouterV2 = require('./routes/v2/userRouter.js');

app.use('/v1/api/users', userRouterV1);
app.use('/v2/api/users', userRouterV2);

app.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('server up an running');
});
```

and your isolated routes version 1 :

```
// /routes/v1/userRouter.js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello v1');
});

module.exports = router;
```

finally your isolated routes version 2 :

```
// /routes/v2/userRouter.js
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hey v2');
});

module.exports = router;
```